# Mongoose shows 0 results when data is there

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb as my backend and it has around 400 documents inside the index _entity.

i am using mongoose with my nodejs and query it as follows,

```
 getCountries : function(event,context,callback){            
              dbHelper.query(mongoose.model('_entity'), {},function(error,data){
              console.log(data);
                callback(data);       
            });
```

here is the dbHelper.

```
query : function(model, conditon,options) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            options = options||{};               
            model.find(conditon, {}, options, function(error, data) {
                if (error)                  
                    reject(error);                    
                resolve(data);
            })
        })
    }
```

is there any issue with the code? when i run the query on mongo client, it shows the results.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're returning a promise in you query so you need to use the .then method instead of a callback.

```
 getCountries : function(event,context,callback){            
          dbHelper.query(mongoose.model('_entity'), {}).then(function(data){

           }); 
 }
```

edit:
If you're using mongoose4 then you can just return a promise with the query itself like so.

```
query : function(model, conditon,options) {
            options = options||{};               
            return model.find(conditon, {}).exec();
    }
```

you'll still need to keep the .then with my previous response.

Comment: That is no the issue, even inside the dbhelper i added a console.log it does not print the data

Comment: I updated my response with a better way to return the promise

Comment: still it returns 0, no idea why

Comment: make sure to add your schema in mongoose.model(''_entity", schema)

Comment: I need to see the rest of your code in order to help you further. I don't know where or how you're defining your schemas